# New "snip & sketch" feature in Windows 10 October Update is too slow (how to reduce the delay)?

Tags: windows, windows-10, clipboard, screenshot, snipping-tool

If anyone has just received the new Windows 10 October Update, you'll see a new feature has been implemented: Win key + Shift + S now opens the 'snip and sketch' tool for selecting regions of the screen to copy to clipboard.

While this is a useful feature in theory, the new implementation of it is slow and annoying - i.e. there's a second or so delay initially while the screen fades to grey (before you can select the region) and after making a selection, the selected region is highlighted for a little while, preventing you from going back to your application and actually  using the screenshot!

In contrast, this same feature has been built into OneNote for years and worked instantaneously with no delay.

I appreciate a delay of a few seconds is small, but it's a very irritating change. I wonder if anyone else has experienced this, and if there's a way to reduce the delay (snip and sketch does not appear to have any settings options).

Comment: it has always been instantaneous on my PCs in all Windows 10 versions. And it does have an option to [take snip after a delay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unSsM.png). Probably it has been enabled by default somehow

Comment: Did you figure out how to fix it? I just got this problem last few months